# Retrieve a Magento shopping cart store in database on the frontend?

Tags: web-services, magento, checkout, shopping-cart

I've 2 websites : One main ecommerce store running Magento. The other one is a hand self made shop, where i use the magento product of the first website.

On the second website, i've build a shopping cart using magento webservice. My cart is running well, but when it's time to to proceed chekout i want to be redirect on the magento main website to paid the command.

My trouble is here : How to retrieve my shopping cart build with the webservice on the main magento store where the cart seems to be stored in session? I've found that shopping cart build with webservices where stored in the "sales_quotes" tables. How to get them on the frontend?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how mangento handle multi store by passing a session id, if you could get session id from your api/other store then you could accomplish this. You could also try to get the quote id and forward it to magento store when recreate their cart.

It maybe easier if you add product to cart using the the store url (eg http://magentoserver.com/checkout/cart/add?product=13&qty=1&options[12]=57) then redirecting them back to your other store. This way you would not have to try to get the session id.